# Magento media urls breaking in sub-store

Tags: magento, path, http-status-code-404, magento-1.7

Got a bit of a problem. Recently migrated my magento (1.7) store to a new host - no change in setup, identical down to the version of php - just pick up and drop. Everything is peachy, the site is running fine, except for one problem.

There's the main store, http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/, then there's a sub-store http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/gearlocker/. The sub-store can't seem to access any media, and I believe I know why.

Here's an example script call for /magento/:

```
http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/js/scriptaculous/builder.js
```

And here's the same script call for /magento/gearlocker/:

```
http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/gearlocker/js/scriptaculous/builder.js
```

The files are being called absolutely, so I know it's not a relative path issue. From the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/gearlocker/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
```

It was fine on the original host, but it all started breaking when we migrated. Has anyone run into this kind of problem before? I'm hoping it's just a config issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple solution, as it turns out.

The culprit was a misleading path in core_config_data - web/unsecure/base_url was set to /magento/gearlocker/ when it needed to be /magento/. Stupid mistake!